# jQuery Plug-in - How to external call to a function with initialized parameters

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, external

I'm trying to write a plugin automates toggling stuffs for panels in jQuery. Everything works fine if i dont need to call a function externally, defined in my plugin, for specified element with initialized settings. I'm stuck in this case. To give an example; i've a function named 'toggle(domEle)' gets an element as parameter and toggles it off if is on, else toggles on. Inside this function, it calls two other functions named 'toggleOff(domEle)' and 'toggleOn(domEle)'. I want to call any of these functions externally. Because i want to group panels and ensure that only one is 'on' of a group at the same time. So i get all of a group but cant call 'toggleOff' method for them.

```
$("#someElement").togglePanel({options}); // initialize the plugin.

//Now it works fine with binded trigger events passed in options.
//But i want to call toggling functions externally like this or somehow:

$("#someElement").togglePanel().toggleOff();
//Or
$("#someElement").togglePanel.toggleOff();
//Or how it must be.
```

Here is my complete code. I hope i could explain whats my problem.

```
//Toggle Panel
(function ($) {
    var methods = {
        //init method
        init: function (domEle, settings) {
            if (!methods.getSettings(domEle)) {
                switch (settings.position) {
                    case "top":
                        $(domEle).css("margin-top", settings.margin);
                        break;
                    case "bottom":
                        $(domEle).css("margin-bottom", settings.margin);
                        break;
                    case "left":
                        $(domEle).css("margin-left", settings.margin);
                        break;
                    case "right":
                        $(domEle).css("margin-right", settings.margin);
                        break;
                }
                $(domEle).css("position", "absolute");
                $(domEle).css("z-index", settings.zindex);
                methods.setToggleStatus(domEle, "on");
                methods.setToggleGroup(domEle, settings.toggleGroup);
                $(settings.triggers).each(function (index, elem) {
                    $(elem.selector).bind(elem.eventName, function (e) {
                        methods.toggle(domEle);
                    });
                });
                methods.setSettings(domEle, settings);
                methods.toggleOff(domEle, false);
            }
        },
        //toggle method
        toggle: function (domEle) {
            if (methods.getAnimatingStatus(domEle) == "true") return;
            if (methods.getToggleStatus(domEle) == "on") {
                methods.toggleOff(domEle);
            }
            else {
                methods.toggleOn(domEle);
            }
        },
        //toggleOn method
        toggleOn: function (domEle, useAnimation) {
            if (methods.getAnimatingStatus(domEle) == "true") return;
            var settings = methods.getSettings(domEle);
            useAnimation = typeof useAnimation !== 'undefined' ? useAnimation : settings.useAnimation;
            if (methods.getToggleStatus(domEle) == "off") {
                if (useAnimation) {
                    methods.toggleStart(domEle);
                    switch (settings.position) {
                        case "top":
                            $(domEle).animate({ top: 0 }, settings.animDuration, null, function () { methods.toggleComplete(domEle); });
                            break;
                        case "bottom":
                            $(domEle).animate({ bottom: 0 }, settings.animDuration, null, function () { methods.toggleComplete(domEle); });
                            break;
                        case "left":
                            $(domEle).animate({ left: 0 }, settings.animDuration, null, function () { methods.toggleComplete(domEle); });
                            break;
                        case "right":
                            $(domEle).animate({ right: 0 }, settings.animDuration, null, function () { methods.toggleComplete(domEle); });
                            break;
                    }
                }
                else {
                    switch (settings.position) {
                        case "top":
                            $(domEle).css({ top: 0 });
                            break;
                        case "bottom":
                            $(domEle).css({ bottom: 0 });
                            break;
                        case "left":
                            $(domEle).css({ left: 0 });
                            break;
                        case "right":
                            $(domEle).css({ right: 0 });
                            break;
                    }
                }
                methods.setToggleStatus(domEle, "on");
            }
        },
        //toggleOff method
        toggleOff: function (domEle, useAnimation) {
            if (methods.getAnimatingStatus(domEle) == "true") return;
            var settings = methods.getSettings(domEle);
            useAnimation = typeof useAnimation !== 'undefined' ? useAnimation : settings.useAnimation;
            var width = $(domEle).width();
            var height = $(domEle).height();
            if (methods.getToggleStatus(domEle) == "on") {
                if (useAnimation) {
                    methods.toggleStart(domEle);
                    switch (settings.position) {
                        case "top":
                            $(domEle).animate({ top: -height }, settings.animDuration, null, function () { methods.toggleComplete(domEle); });
                            break;
                        case "bottom":
                            $(domEle).animate({ bottom: -height }, settings.animDuration, null, function () { methods.toggleComplete(domEle); });
                            break;
                        case "left":
                            $(domEle).animate({ left: -width }, settings.animDuration, null, function () { methods.toggleComplete(domEle); });
                            break;
                        case "right":
                            $(domEle).animate({ right: -width }, settings.animDuration, null, function () { methods.toggleComplete(domEle); });
                            break;
                    }
                }
                else {
                    switch (settings.position) {
                        case "top":
                            $(domEle).css({ top: -height });
                            break;
                        case "bottom":
                            $(domEle).css({ bottom: -height });
                            break;
                        case "left":
                            $(domEle).css({ left: -width });
                            break;
                        case "right":
                            $(domEle).css({ right: -width });
                            break;
                    }
                }
                methods.setToggleStatus(domEle, "off");
            }
        },
        //toggleStart
        toggleStart: function (domEle) {
            methods.setAnimatingStatus(domEle, true);
            methods.getSettings(domEle).toggleStart();
        },
        //toggleComplete
        toggleComplete: function (domEle) {
            methods.setAnimatingStatus(domEle, false);
            methods.getSettings(domEle).toggleComplete();
        },
        //getToggleStatus method
        getToggleStatus: function (domEle) { return $(domEle).attr("toggleStatus"); },
        //setToggleStatus method
        setToggleStatus: function (domEle, status) { $(domEle).attr("toggleStatus", status); },
        //getToggleGroup method
        getToggleGroup: function (domEle) { return $(domEle).attr("toggleGroup"); },
        //setToggleGroup method
        setToggleGroup: function (domEle, group) { $(domEle).attr("toggleGroup", group); },
        //getAnimatingStatus
        getAnimatingStatus: function (domEle) { return $(domEle).attr("isAnimating"); },
        //setAnimatingStatus
        setAnimatingStatus: function (domEle, status) { $(domEle).attr("isAnimating", status); },
        //getSettings
        getSettings: function (domEle) { return jQuery(domEle).data("settings"); },
        //setSettings
        setSettings: function (domEle, settings) { jQuery(domEle).data("settings", settings); }
    }

    jQuery.fn.togglePanel = function (options) {
        jQuery.fn.togglePanel.toggleOff = function () { methods.toggleOff($(this)); };
        jQuery.fn.togglePanel.toggleOn = function () { methods.toggleOn($(this)); };
        jQuery.fn.togglePanel.toggle = function () { methods.toggle($(this)); };
        jQuery.fn.togglePanel.defaults = {
            position: "top",
            margin: 0,
            zindex: -1,
            useAnimation: true,
            animDuration: 400,
            triggers: {},
            toggleStart: function () { },
            toggleComplete: function () { },
            toggleGroup: "_none_"
        };
        var $this = $(this);
        var settings = jQuery.extend(jQuery.fn.togglePanel.defaults, options);
        methods.init($this, settings);
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do something like this

```
var methods = {
    toggleOn: ...,
    toggleOff: ...,
    init: function(obj) {
        ...
    }
}

$.fn.togglePanel= function( method ) {    
  if ( methods[method] ) {
    return methods[method].apply( 
     this, Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 )
    );
  } else if ( typeof method === 'object' || ! method ) {
    return methods.init.apply( this, arguments );
  } else {
    $.error( 'Method ' +  method + ' does not exist' );
  }      
};
```

So you could call the methods by `.togglePanel('toggleOff')`

Your attempt would be a contradiction to the usual jQuery chaining.

Comment: Thank you, that solved my problem. I changed it a little to fit my needs.